# EL wire and Raspi- is it safe and possible?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, el-wire

I want to connect EL wire to my raspberry pi and control it via GPIO, but was wondering about the safety of this setup. My main concern is that EL wire uses AC current, but the raspberry pi supplies DC. The wire I plan on using [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YG7HQV9) has an inverter built into the battery pack, so I think I should be fine there. I was planning on connecting power from the pi to the + lead in the battery pack leading out, and a ground to the - lead of the returning wire. The power from the pi will be 3.3v, which should be sufficient to power the wire, but is slightly over. Another thing I was worried about is how fast I can turn the wire on/off quickly to make it appear dimmer. So my questions are these-

1. Is it safe to connect the lead to the battery pack, or am I inadvertently bypassing any safety features in the battery pack?
2. Is 3.3v a safe voltage? I've heard it will decrease the overall life of the EL wire, but by how much? Is it worth buying a step down converter to save it?
3. The converter is built into the battery pack, so I think it should work fine by connecting the pi to the battery leads, but will the extra power hurt it in any way?
4. How fast can I turn the EL wire on/off per second? Will this reduce the life or overall brightness of the wire? (I know if you blink an LED fast enough, it appears dimmer, and I'm assuming EL wire functions the same way)

Comment: Please draw a schematic, include part numbers.

Comment: You might try this low voltage flexible filament which runs on 3V -- search for  "Edison fluorescent arc filament soft filament light source". See a review here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0mj15V0twg&t=691s

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track in that you need to control the EL wire at the power supply input (equivalent to popping the batteries in/out, or activating its mechanical switch). You definitely don't want to try switching the output side; the output is ~100V AC which is harder to deal with.

Here's something to get you started:

You can model your EL wire power supply as a load that needs about 3V and something less than 1A. (Based on the ~6 hour life I've observed from them, it probably draws around 100-200mA, but it's better to design for 1A to be conservative.)

Raspberry Pi GPIO pins are limited to about 20mA output, so you'll break your Pi if you try to make a GPIO pin power the thing directly. Instead, you need to make the GPIO pin control a transistor (an NPN or NMOS rated for 1A or more) which will handle the switching of actual current.

So your circuit should be:

- GPIO -> 200 ohm resistor -> NPN transistor gate
- Power supply battery compartment (-) -> NPN transistor collector (the higher voltage side)
- Actual battery (-) -> NPN transistor emitter (the lower voltage side)
- Connect a wire from actual battery (-) to the Raspberry Pi GND. (This will be the return path for the current sent into the transistor gate.)

If you look up circuits to control a motor from a Raspberry Pi, it's the same idea. Basically the NPN transistor switches the low side of the load, so when it's on it will connect the EL power supply (-) to the (-) of the battery. You can use the same transistors and resistors that people use to control motors.

Comment: I looked through my box of electrical components and found a relay that says-

JZC-11F

005-1Z

5VDC

T-85*C 220/250VAC 5A

I'm pretty sure that this will carry the current of the EL wire, before or after the inverter, but wanted to check. If I can use this, then I can use it to replace the switch on the wire, assuming I'm not skipping the inverter. just wanted to check , but will this relay work for the EL wire? The wire will have a separate power supply of 2 AA independent from the pi.

Comment: Yeah, the EL wire is < 250VAC and much less than 5A, so with that relay you could switch either the EL wire side or the battery side. If switching the EL side, my only concern is that the EL wire power supply may shut itself down if it detects that it's not connected to an EL wire load. Easy to test though -- if you unplug/replug the EL wire and it comes back on, your plan will work. 

Also, to be safe, measure the resistance of the relay's coil: if 3.3V / (coil resistance) ends up greater than 0.02A, then you can't power the relay straight from a GPIO pin. You'll need to use a transistor.

Comment: I googled for that relay's datasheet, and it looks like the relay coil draws 80mA: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/5/e/d/e/a/DS-00100-Relay_SPDT_Sealed.pdf

So you'll definitely need to use a transistor. Connect one side of the relay coil to 5V, and connect the other to GND through a small NPN transistor (whose gate is connected to the GPIO pin through a roughly 200ohm resistor). Then your GPIO pin will be able to activate the transistor which activates the relay.